# Perl question. Need a way to replace two variables on the same line

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a replace script in Perl, and I have it working halfway, but it seems that I cannot replace two strings in the same line.

I have a json file named **foo.json** that contains the following line: `"title": "%CLIENT% Dashboard Web Map %WEBMAPENV%",`

Now, I have a second file named **env.txt** that contains all the variables that I wish to use.  In this file, there is an entry called: `%WEBMAPENV%=(Test-Dev)`.  My goal is to have PERL read the file env.txt, and replace BOTH "%CLIENT% and %WEBMAPENV% simultaneously.

Here is my code so far:

```
my $envFilePath = "$dirScripts/env/env.txt";

# Reading Firebase variables from Test environment file.
open($fh, "<", $envFilePath);

while (my $line=<$fh>) {
  if ($line eq "\n") {
    next;
  }

  if ($line =~ m/^(%\w+%)=/) {
    $cur_key = $1;

    $line =~ s/$cur_key=//;

    $replacements{$cur_key} = $line;
  } else {
    $replacements{$cur_key} .= $line;
  }
}
```

...

```
my $targetFilePath3 = "$dirHome/foo.json";

tie my @v_lines, 'Tie::File', $targetFilePath3, autochomp => 0 or die $!;

replaceEnvVars(@v_lines);

# Replace the environment variables as part of the setup.
sub replaceEnvVars {

for my $line (@_) {
  if ($line =~ m/(%\w+%)/) {
    my $key = $1;
    if (defined($replacements{$key})) {
      my $value = $replacements{$key};
      chomp $value;
      $line =~ s/$key/$value/g;
    }
  }
}
untie @_;
}
```

I am only able to substitute one variable per line, but I need to be able to handle 2.

Can any offer some help?

Derek

Comment: Tip: You should NEVER use Tie::File. It doesn't make the code any simpler; it doesn't save memory, and it makes things up to 30x slower!

Comment: If at all possible, use an existing templating library such as [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Manual/Intro.pod). It's more powerful, less buggy, and better documented.

Comment: Tie::File has its uses, but its inappropriate for simply iterating through a file like this.

Comment: Re "*Tie::File has its uses*", I've yet to come across one, and I've asked a lot. Do you have an example? @Schwern

Comment: It can't be used for large files since it keeps an index of each line in the file. This is above any amount of memory in its cache. While you can can control the size of the cache, you can't control of the size of the index. This means that for files with short average lines, File::Tie uses more memory than it would take to load the entire file into memory. So if you don't have enough memory to load the entire file, you don't have enough memory to use Tie::File.

Comment: So what about short files, then? Well, it's pointless to use for short files. Massive speed penalties means you might as well just read short file entirely into memory. (I clocked T::F taking 30x longer for some simple operation.)

Comment: What does that leave? Code simplicity? Most of the time, it doesn't really make the code any simpler, especially given the availability of File::ReadBackwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only check for one.

```
 if ($line =~ m/(%\w+%)/) { ... }
```

Solution:

```perl
# Clean up %replacements before using it.
chomp for values %replacements;

for my $line (@_) {
  $line =~ s{(%\w+%)}{ $replacements{$1} // $1 }eg;
}
```

By adding a loop inside of `s///` (through the use of `/g`) rather than a loop around `s///`, this one doesn't mess up if the values contain `%`.

`/e` means the replacement will be run as Perl code.

`//` is the "defined-or" operator. It works like `||` but looks for `defined` rather than truth.

See the [Perl Regex Tutorial](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) for more.

Comment: Thanks to @Schwern for his contributions.